# create directory as an ssh link

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'd like to create a directory that links to external site via ssh.
So that when I cd to /var/remote/dev01 it will actually cd to a folder on a remote site.
So I'm staying on my current terminal and can copy files from any other dir to this /var/remote/dev01 dir and it will copy the files over to the remote host.
Is this even doable?

Comment: It's OffTopic, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible. Take a look at [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). It lets you mount a remote filesystem over ssh, and treat it as a local mountpoint, for standard filesystem operations.

Here's a nice [walkthrough](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) to get you started.